# Voltage regulator equation

Tags: voltage-regulator, buck, gain

I'm designing a circuit using this buck regulator (AOZ2253TQI-20) from Alpha & Omega. Data sheet here, http://www.aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AOZ2253TQI-20.pdf

The data sheet doesn't specifically say the output voltage based on the feedback resistors, however I assume its similar to other regulators and something like, Vout=(R2/R1+1)*something.  My first question is, what exactly will this equation be for this chip and how do I find that?

Secondly, I'm a bit confused by the table of maximum possible ratings shown here (or on page 5 of the data sheet).  This suggests the FB pin must be within 6V of ground, but my understanding was that to get an output voltage as close as possible to the input voltage, the FB should be close to the output voltage, in this case up to 30V.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: FB pin uses a voltage divider, as in the R1 and R2, to put the voltage range within ratings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. On page 7 and 9 of the datasheet, you can see that the feedback voltage, VFB, is 0.8V. With that you can use 0.8*(1+R1/R2) to set the output voltage, where R1 is the higher leg on the voltage divider. It's a bit unfortunate that the datasheet doesn't explicitly call it out but that is what you need.

[image: Pg 7]
[image: Pg 9]

2. The maximum rating for VFB is the spec to which you can cause permanent damage to the device, so it should not be near that level under normal operating conditions. Even if you were to set the regulator output to, say, 15V, R1 and R2 will feed a portion of that back to the FB line, which should be lower than than 6V because the control loop will try to make it 0.8V as well to match the internal reference voltage of 0.8V. The control loop does that by adjusting the output voltage.

Comment: Thanks.  An additional related question is then in regards to the maximum FB current and the values of R1 and R2.  The max feedback current is stated as 200nA.  I was planning to make the supply adjustable with R1 varying from 0-50k and R2=3k (i.e 0.8V - ~14V).  That seems to me like it should work, but just checking.